# SQL Relational model links

Tags: sql, relational-database, diagram, erd

Can anyone explain the links between the tables? like sometimes there's a bubble, other times a rectangle appears and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an entity-relationship diagram (ERD) using [Crow's foot notation](https://vertabelo.com/blog/crow-s-foot-notation/).  The lines represent relationships between tables. In this variant of the notation, the `*` identifies the primary key of a table.

At each end of a relationship, you will find two symbols:

- closest to the table: a `|` or 3 lines joining. The first means a **cardinality** of maximum 1 and the second a cardinality maximum  N (i.e. "many").
- next to the first symbol, either a `|` or a `O` :  The first means a mandatory **participation** (i.e. minimum 1) and the second an optional participation (i.e. minimum is 0).

So, combining the two gives 4 possibilities:

- [image] means "none or 1" (aka `0..1`),
- [image] means "1 and exactly 1" (aka `1..1`),
- [image: ![enter image description here] means "none, one or many" (aka `0..n`), and
- the last combination, which is not on your diagram, would mean "1 or more" (i.e. `1..n`)

Answer (score 0):

That’s called Crow’s Foot notation and is a standard way of indicating the cardinality of a relationship between two entities